# How do you auto update a string(in JLabel) from textboxes?

Tags: java, swing

I am a computer science student doing my first project on the side. I deliver pizza so i figured I would make a program that aids delivery drivers. I am just starting on it today.

Here is a pic: [image: Delivery Helper]

Right now, you have to press enter after typing in a value in any of the boxes. I want to make it where the value under hourly earnings autoupdates when tips and hours worked boxes have numbers in them. With no need to press enter.

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for your textfields and update the appropriate JLabel in your Listener implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you want the update to occur, you could (as has been suggested) a DocumentListener, which will allow updates in real time (as you type) or if you just want the values to change when you move to the next field (ie tab or click), you could use a [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html)